# Use MVC Razor pages in Asp.Net Core 2.1 console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.1

I've been trying to implement the [IdentityServer4 Quickstart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) in my application. However, my IdentityServer is already running within a ASP.NET Core 2.1 console application. So I've been trying to get MVC working within my app.

No matter what I do I always ends up with the following error:

```
   Connection id "0HLF37NOM2HND", Request id "0HLF37NOM2HND:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
   System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
   /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

The controller is fine, but compiling the view (and/or finding the cshtml is not working). I never get a ConsoleApp1.Views.dll in the output folder.

So I created a fresh ASP.NET MVC application from the template in Visual Studio, and also create a new Console application. I then copied over all of the files from the MVC app to the Console app and included the necessary nuget packages. But I'm still getting the same error. The views are located directly in a View folder the project root.

[image]

I'm I missing something? Could I ever make the Razor pages work in a **Microsoft.NET.Sdk** project?

I've uploaded my test application here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rfFsumn4g_StXNShhz5eOUa6WNz5JO5c

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the Views are found if i change to Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" in .csproj. However I would like to avoid changing my larger console application to a webapp

Comment: What makes you think you will get a `ConsoleApp1.Views.dll` file?

Comment: The MVC project outputs a `WebApplication1.Views.dll`, I'm guessing it's all part of the Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"? Thought naively that .cshtml files always compiled in Core 2.1

Comment: You do realize that an ASP.NET Core Web App *is* a console app, right? You're basically taking code from a console app that already has all the functionality you want, and trying to move it to another console app with none of that set up yet. By the time you get all the set up correct, you'll have the original web app you started with.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm only doing it to simplify the problem. The "real" console app is a much larger application, where a webhost with IdentityServer4 are running. I would like to avoid changing the "Project Sdk" for the whole application just to get the Views to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You'll need to use Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor to use this in console \ class library application.

https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2462